# Pattern match multiple values in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pattern-matching

I have a sentence that has a specific format.

```
<subject> <action> <object> @ <price> ... // The sentence can continue
```

and I want to extract these values out of the sentence.

Constraints:

- The subject is always `Bob` or `Alice`
- Action is either `bought` or `sold`
- The object can be any word of 1-7 letters // `4apples` should return NULL
- Price is either a float/integer
- There can be sentences before `subject` but guaranteed to not
  contain `Bob/Alice`.
- There may or may not be a space after `@`

Example:

```
Hi there, Bob sold apples @2.0 dollars each
```

Desired Output:

```
Subject: Bob
Action: sold
Object: apples
Price: 2.0
```

Currently, I do it the naive way by:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

sentence = "Hi there, alice sold apples @2.0 dollars each"

sentence = sentence.lower()

if 'alice' in sentence or 'bob' in sentence:

    s_list = sentence.split(" ")
    s_idx = -1

    if 'bob' in sentence:
        s_idx = s_list.index('bob')
    elif 'alice' in sentence:
        s_idx = s_list.index('alice')

    if s_idx > -1:
        Subject = s_list[s_idx]
        Action = s_list[s_idx+1]
        Object = s_list[s_idx+2]  #more if/else to validate Object contraints
        Price = s_list[s_idx+3]   #more if/else to extract 2.0 if we get @2.0 

    print("Subject: {}, Action: {}, Object: {}, Price: {}".format(Subject, Action, Object, Price))
```

How can I do this better? Possibly using `re`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regex with a named capturing group for each element:

```py
import re

sentence = "Hi there, alice sold apples @2.0 dollars each"

values = re.search('(?P<subject>bob|alice)\s+(?P<action>bought|sold)\s+(?P<object>[A-Za-z]{1,7})\s+@\s*(?P<price>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', sentence)
if values:
    Subject = values['subject']
    Action = values['action']
    Object = values['object']
    Price = values['price']
    print("Subject: {}, Action: {}, Object: {}, Price: {}".format(Subject, Action, Object, Price))
```

This will output

```
Subject: alice, Action: sold, Object: apples, Price: 2.0
```

Note you may want to supply the [`re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20search#re.I) flag to [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re%20search#re.search) to allow for `bob` or `Bob` (or `Sold` or `sold` etc.) to be matched; in that case you could replace `[A-Za-z]` in the `object` capture group with `[a-z]`.

Comment: Thanks, are we able to return other values if one doesn't match - meaning if `4apples` was there in the sentence, how can we still return the other variables?

Comment: You could wrap each capture group like this: `(?:(?P<subject>bob|alice)|[^\s]+)` and then use something like `Subject = values['subject'] or 'not found'`

Comment: In my above comment, I would like to have the output: `Subject: alice, Action: sold, Object: None, Price: 2.0`. I don't need it for any other values than the object, but still interesting to know if that is much more complicated.

Comment: Just leave the code as is then, and replace `(?P<object>[A-Za-z]{1,7})` with `(?:(?P<object>[a-z]{1,7})|[^\s]+)`. Demo on rextester: https://rextester.com/SCN47430